# How to fetch ID from below html string

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

While using selector

```
$(this).children('td ').eq(0).html()
```

I get

```
<input name="abc" type="checkbox" value="checked" class="check2" id="xyz" checked="">
```

I want to fetch "id" from this input element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).children('td:first').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('id');
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

faster

```
var $t=$(this);

$t.find("> td:first-child").get(0).id
```

edit to answer the comment that disappears :

> Current Winner
>
> Cached .find()
>
> var $a = $('#a');
> $a.find('.b');

http://vaughnroyko.com/the-real-scoop-on-jquery-find-performance/